# Hiding a map and displaying another with onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am building a simple website for a client, they have two studios and they would like to display them on googleMaps in the contact section. Problem is, I cannot display two maps at once. So I would like to make it so that when you click on one address it hides a map and displays the other and vice-versa. Here is the code:

```js
function showMapOne() {
  document.getElementById("mapOne").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("mapTwo").style.display = "none";
}

function showMapTwo() {
  document.getElementById("mapOne").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("mapTwo").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#addressOne {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: "arial";
}

#mapOne {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 500px;
}

#addressTwo {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 500px;
  font-family: "arial";
}

#mapTwo {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="addressOne">
  <a href="#" onClick="showMapOne">Via G. Mattei, 114 - Arese - MI</a>
</div>

<div id="addressTwo">
  <a href="#" onClick="showMapTwo">Via Miralago, 12 - Laveno Mombello -    VA</a>
</div>

<div id="mapDivOne">
  <div id="mapOne"></div>
</div>

<div id="mapDivTwo">
  <div id="mapTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing the () on the call

Comment: edit of @mplungjan: onClick="showMapOne()" and ´onClick="showMapTwo()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the () in the function call `onClick="showMapOne()"` and `onClick="showMapTwo()"`

Perhaps you mean this?

```js
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("address_One").onclick=document.getElementById("address_Two").onclick=function() {
    var id = this.id.split("_")[1];
    document.getElementById("mapOne").style.display = id=="One"?"block":"none";
    document.getElementById("mapTwo").style.display = id=="Two"?"block":"none";
  }
}
```

```css
#addressOne {
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: "arial";
}

#mapOne {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 500px;
}

#addressTwo {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 500px;
  font-family: "arial";
}

#mapTwo {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 1050px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="address_One" href="#">Via G. Mattei, 114 - Arese - MI</a>
</div>
<div id="mapOne">Map 1</div>
<div id="addressTwo">
  <a href="#" id="address_Two" >Via Miralago, 12 - Laveno Mombello -    VA</a>
</div>
<div id="mapTwo">Map 2</div>
```

Comment: mplungjan, thank you for your help. Your code works, unfortunately googlemaps still won't display the second map, even if the display function is set to "none".

Comment: Ah, you can remove the map from one dive and lid into the other or search so how to display two maps on one page

Comment: Thanks, I have looked up how to display two maps, some people seem to have a work around. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Apologies for the typos in previous comment. Mobile in low light :)